# Active Record Could not find table

Tags: ruby, activerecord

I'm learning Active Record and have written a simple example below:

```
#!/usr/bin/ruby

require 'active_record'
require 'sqlite3'

ActiveRecord::Base.establish_connection(
  adapter:  'sqlite3',
  database: 'test.sqlite3',
)

class Network < ActiveRecord::Base
end

network = Network.create(name: "Network1")

puts Network.all
```

but this results in an error message:

```
/var/lib/gems/2.1.0/gems/activerecord-4.2.5/lib/active_record/connection_adapters/sqlite3_adapter.rb:511:in `table_structure': Could not find table 'networks' (ActiveRecord::StatementInvalid)
  from /var/lib/gems/2.1.0/gems/activerecord-4.2.5/lib/active_record/connection_adapters/sqlite3_adapter.rb:385:in `columns'
  from /var/lib/gems/2.1.0/gems/activerecord-4.2.5/lib/active_record/connection_adapters/schema_cache.rb:43:in `columns'
  from /var/lib/gems/2.1.0/gems/activerecord-4.2.5/lib/active_record/attributes.rb:93:in `columns'
  from /var/lib/gems/2.1.0/gems/activerecord-4.2.5/lib/active_record/attributes.rb:98:in `columns_hash'
  from /var/lib/gems/2.1.0/gems/activerecord-4.2.5/lib/active_record/inheritance.rb:205:in `subclass_from_attributes?'
  from /var/lib/gems/2.1.0/gems/activerecord-4.2.5/lib/active_record/inheritance.rb:54:in `new'
  from /var/lib/gems/2.1.0/gems/activerecord-4.2.5/lib/active_record/persistence.rb:33:in `create'
  from test.rb:14:in `<main>'
```

What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your database doesn't have the `networks` table. Thus ActiveRecord will throw that error when trying to persist your data.

You should use [create_table](http://apidock.com/rails/ActiveRecord/ConnectionAdapters/SchemaStatements/create_table) method in order to create your table.

```
create_table(:networks) do |t|
  t.column :name, :string
end
```

Comment: I thought it does it naturally? You only have to define column names if you want to override it? I don't want to do that.

Comment: @user5603796 You're using a relational database. Thus it's expected that all your fields are defined before you use your table. To define your fields you must have your table created. In summary you must define your table with all your fields (and types) before using it

Comment: The documentation says to only do that when you want to override the defaults. I don't understand

Comment: http://guides.rubyonrails.org/active_record_basics.html#creating-active-record-models does not agree with you. It does not mention specifying columns etc

Comment: Could you pass what you are referring to? I mean the link you are reading

Comment: It says by default the table will be created with a ID and name column

Comment: Could you please send the link of documentation you're reading?

Comment: http://guides.rubyonrails.org/active_record_basics.html#creating-active-record-models

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/100314/discussion-between-cristiano-alencar-and-user5603796).